# How to make textfield automatic field when dropdown is selected in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter-3

Hallo i'm new in codeigniter, i want to make textinput filled after selected value of dropdown, can anyone give an example for me (for models, conntroller and view) ? thx

here is my dropdown form

```
<div class="form-group">
                                 <?php $id = 'id="nama" class="form-control input-md" required';
                echo form_dropdown('nama',$nama_cabang,'',$id)?>
                                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                    <?php echo form_error('nama_cabang') ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

and its my textinput

```
<div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control <?php echo form_error('kode_cabang') ? 'is-invalid':'' ?>"
                                 type="text" name="kode" placeholder="Kode Cabang" />

                                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                    <?php echo form_error('kode_cabang') ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

how can the value of textinput changed when dropdown is selected.

Comment: this can be done through javascript not by php, change the tag from codeigniter to jquery / javascript but this question is so common must be answered already. search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use javascript `onchange` listener to set the trigger, and assign the text input with the current selected value using `this.value` :

```
<div class="form-group">
    <?php $id = 'id="nama" class="form-control input-md" required onchange="document.getElementById(\'kodeCabang\').value = this.value"';
    echo form_dropdown('nama',$nama_cabang,'',$id)?>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">
        <?php echo form_error('nama_cabang') ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

And add an id attribute (`id="kodeCabang"`) to set the target element :

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control <?php echo form_error('kode_cabang') ? 'is-invalid':'' ?>" id="kodeCabang"
        type="text" name="kode" placeholder="Kode Cabang" />

    <div class="invalid-feedback">
        <?php echo form_error('kode_cabang') ?>
    </div>
</div>
```